# Google Maps Api - Departure_time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to generate some data from google maps api and when i request something like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?language=en&departure_time=1452264400&destination=1%20Empire%20Ave,%20London%20N18%201AB&origin=King%27s%20Cross%20St.%20Pancras&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus&key=xxxxxxx
I receive zero results. The departure date is near the next month. When i set departure_time=now it works but it is not that i am looking for. Any ideas ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the error was that routes are available until the next one or two months. If you request a route that is not actually so soon, there have not set any available transportations so maps return zero results. :)

Answer (score 0):

Google acquires the transit data from external sources (travel agencies). Agencies upload the public transport data to Google using GTFS feeds. You can read about this here:

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/

You are likely experience an issue when a GTFS feed is not available for transit bus directions yet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes but actually it is available. I checked it using Google Maps and checking the specific departure_time.